# Is FQL buggy? having trouble retrieving the entire social stream on my wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I try to use FQL to return all message on my social stream using this statement:

SELECT created_time, message FROM stream WHERE source_id = [USER'S FB ID] limit 10000

It traces all the way back to the very 1st post on my wall but some how some of the posts in the middle are missing (compare with what I can retrieve by clicking the 'Older post..' link on the bottom of my profile page ) and it doesn't seem to have a particular pattern. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FQL has many many problems like this. This is almost certainly a bug. There are many bugs about flq related to this. For example: http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=8387 and http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=10590 and http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=9850. There are LOTS more. I would recommend [file a specific bug](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/) and *hope* that they fix it.

Comment: Thx 4 the links Nathan. Fingers cross.