# Inconsistent result for fetching photos using FQL multiquery

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-fql

I'm intending to fetch any photo that contain some specific criteria from my friends album using FQL. The criteria is based in time-range ($since - $until) and the similarity of the album title based on similarity with some strings (equals to "LIKE" in SQL). This is the FQL multiquery I used to fetch the photos:

```
$multiQuery = '{
"query1":"SELECT uid, name FROM user WHERE uid = me() OR uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())",
"query2":"SELECT aid, object_id, owner, link, created, location, name FROM album WHERE owner IN  (SELECT uid FROM #query1) AND created>= '.$unix_since_date.' AND created<= '.$unix_until_date.' AND (strpos(name,\''.$event.'\')>=0 OR strpos(name,\''.$organization.'\')>=0 OR strpos(name,\''.$location.'\')>=0)",
"query3":"SELECT object_id, pid, aid, owner, src_small, src_big, caption, created, place_id, like_info, comment_info FROM photo WHERE aid IN  (SELECT aid FROM #query2)"
}'; `
```

The problem:
Some user can successfully select photos from their friends based on the criteria. Some users can partially get the result, while some other can not have the selection AT ALL despite they have friends who has uploaded photo albums which matched selected criteria ( and these friends does not restrict their album).

I have been trying to figure out why the selection result is inconsistent between users for days. Any ideas?

Comment: Your query looks fine to me. I would say it's due to FQL limits, but Facebook is a bit vague when it comes to telling what those limits are.

Comment: By the way, I wonder, can I replace the multiquery statements using Graph API with different result? Sorry to ask this, I haven't been familiar with Graph API.

Comment: The strength of FQL is really the nested queries; that's usually a lot harder with Graph API (efficiently).

Comment: These threads might be related. Facebook has bugs regarding FQL usage. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979863/is-fql-buggy-having-trouble-retrieving-the-entire-social-stream-on-my-wall , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520056/fql-query-response-randomly-omits-some-results